# JavaScript global boolean Variable convert itself to string

Tags: javascript, string, types, initialization, boolean

first I'm new to Javascript, so please don't hate me if I ask such an trivial question.

I've searched some hours on Google, but I cannot find a solution for my Problem. I have declared a global Variable "status", which is false. But if I check the datatype within a function, it says "string", which is allways true, so that my Script doens't work at all.

```js
var status = false;

function slide(element) {
    if (status) {
        slideUp(element);
    } else {
        slideDown(element);
    }
}

function slideDown(element) {
    status = true;
    // Testprint todo remove
    alert('Status is ' + status + ' and is type: ' + typeof status);
    // todo
}

function slideUp(element) {
    status = false;
    // Testprint todo remove
    alert('Status is ' + status + ' and is type: ' + typeof status);
    // todo
}
```

Am I wrong or have I write myself a function to convert every time a boolean var to a "real" boolean var? I have tested it by myself and this show me boolean datatype...

This works fine...

```js
var test = false;
myTestFunc();

myTestFunc() {
    if(!test) {
      test = true;
      alert('Test is false');
    } else {
      test = false;
      alert('Test is true');
    }
    
    alert('Test contains: ' + test + ' and has the type: ' + typeof test);
}
```

I see, that Javascript seems to randomly declare Variables. Is there a solution to make my Variable to a boolean datatype?

Better is there a chance to force the initialation to boolean like `int varname`?

Comment: `alert` and `console.log` typecasts everything to `string`

Comment: Document write say also "status is true and is type: string"... And my var is everytime true I tested it in the Debugger of my Browser. Even if I don't use "alert"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is window.status - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status

change the name (or scope) of the var and it's all sweet

Answer (score 0):

For boolen use this way from MDN [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean)

```
var test = new Boolean(false);
```

Comment: I found this too. And it changes nothing. It was still a String (even without alert)